# How to create a multi-column contains query in cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax

For a situation like the one below

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   foo text,
   bar set<text>,
   other int
   stuff ascii
   PRIMARY KEY(foo, bar)
);
```

Would the query

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (foo, bar) IN (("foo", "foo"))
```

return something if `foo == "foo" and bar.contains("foo")` , or `foo == "foo" or bar.contains("foo")`, or maybe something completely different?
I would like to get `foo == "foo" or bar.contains("foo")` how should I do this?
Is it possible to build a multi-column contains query using the dataStax query builder in cassandra 3 and scala/java?

Comment: Side note: If you want to use a collection as part of the primary key then you have to declare the column as `frozen`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, an OR clause is not yet possible in Cassandra. That support is being added as a part of the SASI indexing: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html

You can see the progress here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10765

Since you are interested in rows that can be found with only a clustering column, you will be relying on some sort of Secondary Index for this query.